# PHP Play HLS m3u8 File from outside root Nginx FFmpeg

Tags: php, nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have the nginx root is : `/home/krasic/wwwdir/`

PHP script on : `/home/krasic/wwwdir/stream.php`

and streams folder is on `/home/krasic/hls/`

Now the content of m3u8 look like :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:19
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_19.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_20.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_21.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_22.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_23.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
95_24.ts
```

I can read the `m3u8` but cannot output the segments video which exist on the `m3u8 file` using `readfile("/home/krasic/hls/news.m3u8");`

Comment: Segments must be in a web-accessible dir if you plan to serve them with nginx. You can use absolute or relative URLs inside the `m3u8` playlist.

Comment: salut aergistal , however , what about editing the m3u8 in the fly and serving it? above config should look like http://pastebin.com/xPgYuRBj after editing , however not sure how to serve the variable that contain the new editing m3u8 to redirect $_GET['ts'] to play video from /home/krasic/hls/

Comment: The question is why you want to keep them out of web root. Maybe there's a better alternative.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion to put abosute/relative but dont work give error always nginx point from wwwdir + the new abosulte path of stream. I would like to secure streams link that's why i did that , i have a second idea but it has a >5 second delay or so before getting picture, is to create on nginx conf an alias that point to streams folder as root , however with that i cant use echo readfile option , only X-Accel-Redirect (which have delay > 5 second)

Comment: To secure HLS you should put the segments in the web root and use token based authentication instead. Nginx has an [Auth Request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) that uses the return code of a subrequest to auth. You could point it to a `php` script to check the secure token passed in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and return 2xx, 401 or 403 accordingly.

Comment: Or you can [write your own](https://github.com/abedra/nginx-auth-token-module) Nginx auth module.

Comment: i know but that way have some other security issue and far from my need , if you only help in the direction i posted in first post please ? playing hls stream outside root folder ? cause i even edited the segment in the fly with abosulte path not working , sim^ply the absolute path will not work that way as it need iP:PORT address Mean Wan Address, how i can go & solve that with that approch ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110291/discussion-between-aergistal-and-krasic).